# Use timeAverage for column

Tags: package, openair

I have a problem, I want to get the daily accumulations of the precipitation variable with the command **timeAverage** of package **openair**, so I try this:

```
CovTemp <- read.table("CovPrec", header = TRUE, sep = ";", 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, dec = ",", na.strings = "NA")

date <- ajuste_tiempos(CovPrec)
Met_CovPrec <- cbind(date, CovPrec[-c(3,4)])
Met_CovPrec$date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(Met_CovPrec$date,
                                              format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M", "GMT"))


Met_CovPrec_prom_day <- timeAverage(Met_CovPrec, avg.time = "day", statistic = "sum")
```

but the result applies to the entire data frame and not just to the data column:

the original data frame **CovPrec**

MS_NR SS_NR      DATE    HOUR VALUE
1 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:00:00    NA
2 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:10:00    NA
3 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:20:00    NA
4 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:30:00    NA
5 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:40:00    NA
6 13095010   240 1/01/2014 0:50:00    NA

the result **Met_CovPrec_prom_day**:

date                     MS_NR SS_NR VALUE
                       
1 2014-01-01 00:00:00 1885681440 34560     0
2 2014-01-02 00:00:00 1885681440 34560     0
3 2014-01-03 00:00:00 1885681440 34560     0
4 2014-01-04 00:00:00 1885681440 34560    28
5 2014-01-05 00:00:00 1885681440 34560     2
6 2014-01-06 00:00:00 1885681440 34560     0

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1):

"timeAverage" always applies to the entire data frame. You need to select columns, try with:

```
Met_CovPrec_prom_day <- timeAverage(Met_CovPrec[, c("date", "VALUE")], avg.time = "day", statistic = "sum")
```